# select option with similar given text

Tags: jquery

i have a select box with options:

```
<select id="quality_input" name="quality_input" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">--Video's Original--</option>
                <option value="ggg" selected="selected">MP4 (20MB)</option>
                <option value="xxx">WEBM (5MB)</option>
                <option value="yyy">MP4 (3MB)</option>
                <option value="zzz">X-FLV (1.2MB)</option>
                <option value="ppp">3GP (0.5MB)</option>
              </select>
```

And i have a pre-defined chosen option depending on the user settings, let's say it is 'webm', is there a way with ajax that I select the option with 'webm' no matter what the size or value are? I only have some part of the text of the option, how can i select it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what do you mean by _'no matter what the size or value are'_?

Comment: I mean no matter what the other text after the video type is, in my case: Video Type (Size MB). Anyway, Barmar's solution worked fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:contains()` selector:

```
var webm = "WEBM";
$("#quality_input").val($("#quality_input option:contains(" + webm + ")").val());
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant answer than mine was.  Deleted mine in favor of this one

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchString= "webm";

$("#quality_input option").each(function(){
  var value= this.val();
  if(value.indexOf(searchString)>=0){
     $("#quality_input").val(value);
     break;
  }
});
```